# How to revert a feature in hook_update programatically?

Tags: drush, features, deployment

I've created a feature to update a menu. Then in my deploy module, I did this:

```
function phoenix_deploy_update_7106() {
  $feature_list = array(
    'campus_dropdown',
  );
  features_revert($feature_list);
}
```

but then running `drush updb -y` on the staging site, doesn't enable my new menu items.

Have I gotten the commands right to revert the feature?

Comment: What's `campus_dropdown`, name of the component or the module?

Comment: I think your syntax is not correct, as you're not specifying which components you want to revert or use `features_revert_module("campus_dropdown")` instead (if `campus_dropdown` is the module). Check the link below for the right syntax.